# Discord guild consequences for member below minimum age

Tags: rules-and-policies

What are the practical consequences of having users below the minimum age (as defined by the TOS) for a discord guild?

I'd especially appreciate personal experience.

Comment: Is (or was) this question specifically about Discord's global rules? That seems like something you'd have to ask Discord support themselves. This seems like the wrong place for Discord product support (see the last line of the [on-topic help page](/help/on-topic).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Discord TOS doesn't explicitly state what happens to servers who happen to have underage users. The TOS says this regarding age requirements:

> By accessing our services, you confirm that you’re at least 13 years old and meet the minimum age of digital consent in your country. We maintain a list of minimum ages around the world as a resource for you, but we aren’t able to guarantee that it is always accurate.
> If you are old enough to access our services in your country, but not old enough to have authority to consent to our terms, your parent or guardian must agree to our terms on your behalf. Please ask your parent or guardian to read these terms with you. If you’re a parent or legal guardian, and you allow your teenager to use the services, then these terms also apply to you and you’re responsible for your teenager’s activity on the services.

As you can see, the TOS does not outline any specific action to be taken upon finding underage users on your server. However, from personal experience, and advice passed to me from other Discord users, the recommended action for server moderators or admins is to firstly ban the user from your server/guild, and then [report](https://dis.gd/mytickets) the user to Discord.

Despite this, I have yet to see any servers being wiped by Discord Admins for harbouring underage users, and Discord doesn't really take underage users as a very serious threat.